# Calculating p value for intervals in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, intervals, p-value

I need to calculate a p value for different comorbidities (variable name data.family$q_81_SQ00a/b/c/d/e/f... and so on) in two different groups (HM and SM defined by the variable data.family$related.unrelated).

I do it with this loop:

```
lapply(letters[c(1:12)], function(x){

  fisher.test(data.family$related.unrelated,
                          data.family[[paste0("q_81_SQ00", x)]])
  })
```

That works fine! 
Now i want to do the loop in different age intervals i have defined with following code:

```
data.family$agegroup <- cut(data.family$age, 
                       breaks = c(0, 18, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 92), 
                       labels = c("0-18", "18-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80-92"),
                       right = FALSE)
```

How do i make the loop run in each age interval? I know i can do the following:

```
lapply(letters[c(1:12)], function(x){

      fisher.test(data.family$related.unrelated[data.family$agegroup=='18-29'],
                              data.family[[paste0("q_81_SQ00", x)]][data.family$agegroup=='18-29'])
      })
```

Is it possible to avoid having to repeat the code for each age interval and create a loop within a loop?

Comment: Please include some data (use `dput(data.family)`) to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: @RichardTelford i have over 3000 individuals and >200 variables in a large dataframe which is all dataprotected. Not sure how to include data?

Comment: Just include a few individuals/variables. Replace the real data with fake if needed.